# useContext not updating on state change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have managed to convert my class component into a function one allowing me to use `useContext` however I am a little stuck when it comes to using and getting the status of what I need when it's changed.

I have a component called `input.js` which sits in `src/components/input.js`

```
// input.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Button from '../components/button';
import { getData } from '../utils/debugger';
import { DropdownContext } from '../utils/DropdownContext';

function InputForm(props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState('RTS');
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function queryData(dropdown) {
    return axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: `http://xxx/debugger/${dropdown}`,
    })
      .then((res) => res.data.map((k) => k['key']['name']))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleDropdown = async (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    try {
      const newData = await queryData(value);
      setData(newData);
      setDropdown(value);

      if (newData.length > 0) {
        setValue(newData[0]);
      }
      console.log('newData = ' + JSON.stringify(newData));
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error('Could not get data from axios');
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    queryData(dropdown)
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
          setValue(data[0]);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setLoaded(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='flex items-center'>
      <select
        value={dropdown}
        onChange={handleDropdown}
        className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-center cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
        <DropdownContext.Provider value={dropdown}>
          <option value='RTS'>RTS</option>
          <option value='RTB'>RTB</option>
          <option value='MPC'>MPC</option>
          <option value='MPC_DSP'>MPC_DSP</option>
        </DropdownContext.Provider>
      </select>

      <select
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className='relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm px-1 py-3 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm mr-5'>
        {data.map((r) => (
          <option key={r} value={r}>
            {r}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      {/* {console.log('---')}
        {console.log('these will be entered into the getData()')}
        {console.log(`this.state.dropdown = ${dropdown}`)}
        {console.log(`this.state.value = ${value}`)} */}

      <Button onClick={() => getData(dropdown, value)} color='green'>
        Generate
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default InputForm;
```

The component works perfectly fine outside of the context. Now I want to pass the `dropdown` state into `App.js`

```
// App.js
import React, {useContext } from 'react';

import './index.css';

import Button from '../src/components/button';

import RTSButtons from '../src/components/rtsButtons';
import RTBButtons from '../src/components/rtbButtons';
import MPCButtons from '../src/components/mpcButtons';

import { DropdownContext } from '../src/utils/DropdownContext';

const sectionStyles = 'mt-5 border-b pb-5';

export default function App() {
  const buttonState = useContext(DropdownContext);

  console.log(buttonState);



  if (buttonState === 'RTS') {
    console.log('RTS');
    return <RTSButtons />;
  } else if (buttonState === 'RTB') {
    console.log('RTB');
    return <RTBButtons />;
  } else if (buttonState === 'MPC') {
    console.log('MPC');
    return <MPCButtons />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <section id='response' className={`flex justify-between ${sectionStyles}`}>
        <div>
          <Button color='red'>
            <a href='http://exchange-debugger' target='_blank' rel='noreferrer'>
              create a capture
            </a>
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => console.log('Feedback was giving')} color='purple'>
            <a
              href='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfzebOfAeXqGLqAp5E1l2fW1nTqSzYRwpqKG56HPXey9GQLcA/viewform'
              target='_blank'
              rel='noreferrer'>
              feedback
            </a>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>{buttonState}</section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a util file which is the following:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const DropdownContext = createContext('RTS');
```

I now don't really know where to place my `<DropdownContext.Provider value={dropdown}>` To get the correct value so I'm able to pass it over to App.js. I have seen some tutorials that shows it being placed around other components...where as I just want to pass a state into another file of have that state avaiable globally.

Any help would be great, i feel I am very close but so far.

Comment: [Same thing I linked](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) on your last question. If you want to be able to access the context in your App component then the provider has to be *higher* in the render tree: `ReactDOM.render(<MyContext.Provider><App /></MyContext.Provider>, document.getElementById('my-react-root'))` if you want to be able to *change* the thing in the context, instead of passing a string literal pass a state managed by useState or useReducer to the `value` prop of the provider.

Comment: You can checkout the approach [used here](https://github.com/indiana-department-of-transportation/react-ctx-store) if you want to see something more generalized: there's a function `createDataStore` that takes an optional initial state and returns a provider that takes a reducer and a custom hook for accessing the state and dispatching actions. Kinda sorta if you squint at it a poor man's redux.

Comment: ok so I have to wrap my provided around my `<App />` but how can i then provide it the `dropdown` state from `input.js` and use it in `App.js` this is what I am confused about. Thanks

Comment: Posted an answer that hopefully cinches it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a generic recipe for useContext. Say you have a file context.js:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

// No need to export this, we'll create custom hook around it
const SomeCtx = createContext();

// Custom hook, returns array with state, setter
export const useSomeCtx = () => useContext(SomeCtx);

// Convenience hook so you don't have to destructure
// everywhere, returns read-only state
export const useSomeCtxState = () => {
    const [state] = useContext(SomeCtx);
    return state;
};

// Provider, goes in render tree above components where you
// import/use the accessor hooks above.
export const SomeCtxProvider = ({children, init}) => {
    const myCtx = useState(init); // [myCtxState, setMyCtxState]
    return <SomeCtx.Provider value={myCtx}>{children}</SomeCtx.Provider>;
};
```

Then in your index.js:

```js
import {SomeCtxProvider} from './context.js';
// other stuff

// Setting at the root makes the context globally visible, you
// may want to apply the principle of least privilege
// and put this further down in the render tree.
ReactDOM.render(<SomeCtxProvider><App /></SomeCtxProvider>, someDOMElement);
```

Then in your App.js

```js
import {useSomeCtx} from './context.js';
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useSomeCtx(); // or state = useSomeCtxState()
  // whatever
}
```

Now you can make state changes just like you normally would, and any component that uses the hooks you're providing will re-render and get the latest state. You can wire the setter to whatever event listener(s) are required (like a click on your button).

Note that unlike the older pattern where you kept your entire app state in one huge object, you aren't limited to one context. You can have different contexts with their own custom hooks per the pattern above and have them be available at any point in the render tree below where you put the provider (which in the example I gave is at the root, so everywhere in that case).

Also note that this is pretty short and sweet for how powerful it is, *any* component in your entire app can access this just by importing and using the custom hook defined above and will automatically re-render if it changes. You may want to be more careful about handing out the setter, which is why I included the read-only hook: global variables are evil. Although if you have an app that complex you should probably be using `useReducer` and dispatching actions rather than `useState`.

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful...I think I have it working. But how do i give the context a default value? Is it in `const SomeCtx = createContext();` For example `const SomeCtx = createContext('RTS');`

Comment: Pass it as the init property to the provider: <SomeCtxProvider init={'RTS'}><App />....`

Comment: You sir are a god!

Answer (score 0):

- It's better to apply context API for **`consuming components`**
- Take a look at your Submit action. there are 2 approaches to pursue.

  1. **`onSubmit`** on form element
  2. **`onClick`** on button element inside a form through **`type="submit"`**

Seems you're **not sending** anything after a submission using **one of the above-mentioned methods**. check it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can also just pass the state up via a state changing function
and useState in your App.js. Then you can pass the state down to other components.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

As an above picture, react never trigger the changes if you put the whole object into a new object.

Make sure you trigger the changes so that react think there are some changes and react trigger change to Context API.

I highly suggest creating a new object and adding one by one inside that new object and then finally adding to Context.

Comment: don't provide screen shots

Answer (score -1):

[image]

As you see in the above snap, I used two different files and get context from another file and update that context from another file.

Comment: don't provide screen shots