# ReactJs: Uncaught TypeError: setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using useState hook to set an isLoading state in a Context Provider, but i got this error no matter changes I do. Most of the similar errors I found here were mistakes with destructuring by using {} instead of [], I couldn't find any question to compare with my problem.

that's the context

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { IFormSetStates, IRequestProvider, IResponse } from "./types";

export const ContextForms = createContext<IFormSetStates>({} as IFormSetStates)

export default function ContextFormsProvider({children}: IRequestProvider){
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean | undefined>(false)
    const [isRequestDone, setIsRequestDone] = useState(false)
    const arrayOfContacts = [{} as IResponse]

    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([] as IFormSetStates['arrayOfContacts'])

    return (
        <ContextForms.Provider value={{isLoading, setIsLoading, isRequestDone, setIsRequestDone, arrayOfContacts, contacts, setContacts}}>
            {children}
        </ContextForms.Provider>
    )   
}
```

here im using useContext to use setIsLoading

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../../../context/AuthProvider/useAuth";
import useFormContext from "../../../context/ContextFormsProvider/useFormContext";

export default function LoginForm(){
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const contextAuth = useAuth()
    const contextForms = useFormContext()

    useEffect(()=>{
        contextForms.setIsLoading(true)
    }, [contextAuth.token])
```

when the component is load I got this error:

```
       Uncaught TypeError: contextForms.setIsLoading is not a function    @react-refresh:278 
    at index.tsx:19:22
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23049:26)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24816:13)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24781:9)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24768:7)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24756:3)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:26990:3)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26935:14)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26886:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26638:5)
```

i've tried to change this funcion to many types even so this error still happens

here is the types:

```
export interface IFormStates{
    isLoading: boolean | undefined,
    isRequestDone: boolean,
    arrayOfContacts: Array<IResponse>,
    contacts: Array<IResponse>
}

export interface IFormSetStates extends IFormStates {
    setIsLoading: (e: boolean | undefined) => void,
    setIsRequestDone: (e: boolean) => void,
    setContacts: (e: IFormSetStates['arrayOfContacts']) => void
}
```

and useFormContext declaration

```
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ContextForms } from ".";


export default function useFormContext(){
    const context = useContext(ContextForms)

    return context
}
```

EDIT:

the problem was I wrapped only protected routes with ContextFormProvider and forget to do it in login route. Problem solved.

Comment: I don't see `useFormContext` defined in any of the code you've provided, how are we supposed to know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes no `useFormContext` or confirmation that you've wrapped the component in the provider

Comment: Maybe this would help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851743/3757232

Comment: I edited the question with the missing codes but i found the problem through the answer about to wrap ContextFormsProvider before login route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to call `ContextFormsProvider` or put it same level with `LoginForm`

Make sure you have to wrap `ContextFormsProvider` before call `useFormContext` in component
EX

```
function RootComponent() => {
   return (
      <ContextFormsProvider>
           <LoginForm />
      </ContextFormsProvider>
   )
}
```

Comment: That was  exactly the problem! thanks