# Context value not accessible inside inner function of functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am attempting to build a component that takes in an arbitrarily large list of items and displays a chunk of them at a time. As the user scrolls the window down, I want to automatically load more items if any exist.

The problem I am running into is that the my `appState` variable is not acting consistently. When I log it at the top of the component, it always reads the correct value out of the loaded context. However, when I read the value inside the `onScroll` function, it always returns the default uninitialized state. Where did my context go on the inner function?

Here's a stripped down version that illustrates my problem:

**Component**

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { useLifecycles} from 'react-use'
import AppState from '../../models/AppState'
import { Context } from '../../store/create'

export default () => {
    const appState:AppState = useContext(Context)
    console.log('appState.items (root)=', appState.items.length) // Returns `100`, as it should

    useLifecycles(
        () => {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
        },
        () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
        }
    )

    const onScroll = (evt:any) => {
        console.log('appState.items (onScroll)', appState.items.length) // Returns `0` (the default uninitialized state).
    }

    return (
        <div className='ItemList'>
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
            {/* The list of items goes here */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**../../store/create**

```
import React from 'react'
import AppState, { getDefaultState } from '../models/AppState'

let state:AppState = getDefaultState()
export const Context:React.Context<AppState> = React.createContext<AppState>(state)

export const setAppState = (newState:AppState):void => {
  _state = newState
}

export const getAppState = ():AppState => {
  return _state
}
```

I've read the [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), and to my understanding I am not breaking anything. My `useContext` and `useLifecycle` calls are in a fixed order at the top; no conditionals, no loops.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is `_state` defined? Also that is definitely [*not* how to use `useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You might try [this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68851743/3757232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of how `useLifecycles` work. But the problem I can see is that you are binding the event a function. That function has the state in it's closure and so it captures that value of state. Whenever state changes, your handler isn't aware of the state change and so it just keeps using the data that was previously captured. Now to solve it, you need to listen for state change and remove the listener that was previously attached, add the new listener that has new values in its closure. I think the `useLifecycles` should have a dependency option to achieve that. If not the other way could be to use `useEffect` hook.

Edit:
I just checked the `react-use` docs and turns out what you really need is `useEvent`. Look at the example in docs. To make sure it works in your case, you should pass your dependency in `useCallback`.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I just tested this and you're exactly right. If I switch `useLifecycles` out to a `useEffect` with a `[show]` dependency, everything works! I come from a long line of React.Component usage, so I chose the closest hook that matched Component lifecycle events, which was `useLifecycles` -- seems I need to do some mental training to pay closer attention to the `hook` way.

Comment: Yes, hooks are a little tricky and takes a while to get used to. But once you get a hang of it, they work flawlessly and better than Class components.

Comment: Also quick note to anyone else looking, the `useLifecycles` hook does not have a dependency option. So it looks like I'm going to stick with a generic `useEffect`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting me. Also you can use `useEvent` hook from the same library. It looks really neat and might be a better solution for your case.