# React context is undefined when i call it in useContext()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to build a simple authentication system where the logged-in user's username get saved in local storage. But I also want to save it in a state because pages will be rendered differently according to whether the user is logged in or not.

What I am trying to do is I have in my app.js a loggedUser state. I also created a context so that I can change that state from child components such as `RegistrationForm`

When I try to call UserContext i get that it is undefined. Do I need to export it to use it ? If yes, then what is the purpose of context provider and consumer.

This is my code for app.js

```
function App() {
  //logged in user
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(null);
  //create context for user
  const UserContext = createContext({
    loggedUser: null,
    setLoggedUser: () => {},
  });

  //value that will be passed to the context
  const value = {
    loggedUser,
    setLoggedUser,
  };

  //get the logged User if already exists
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoggedUser(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  }, []);

  .
  .
  .
  return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
        .
        .
        .
      </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

This is where I am calling the `useContext` and I get the error that UserContext is not defined

```
export default function RegistrationForm({ onClick }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setLoggedUser } = useContext(UserContext);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Although this isn't strictly speaking a duplicate, [this should answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850880/usecontext-not-updating-on-state-change-in-react/68851743?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C0.0000#68851743). TL;DR: don't export the context itself, export a hook that exposes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define the `UserContext` outside `app.js` and export it.
Then import the `UserContext` in the file where you want to use it.

```
export const UserContext = createContext({
  loggedUser: null,
  setLoggedUser: () => {},
});

function App() {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(null);
  ... ... ...
}
```