# How do I handle my React context providers when testing a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integration-testing, react-context

In my application, I have a **StartupScreen** component, I'm trying to test its content and functionality is working as intended. For example when the user clicks to log in with google (My goal is to mock the actual log in process) and just display that user has logged in.

My issues are that I'm unsure how to handle all my context values which my **StartupScreen** is using, and I'm even getting errors for values that my **StartupScreen** component isn't directly using.

My StartupScreen component is using a lot of context values like:

```
    
    const { isLoggedIn } = useContext(UserContext);

    const { gameStarted, toggleGameState } = useContext(GameStateContext);

    const { handleLoginClick } = useContext(DatabaseContext);
```

And this is how my test for the component currently looks:

```
describe("StartupScreen component", () => {

    it("mocks google log in and displays users score if they have played before", async () => {

        const mockHandleLoginClick = vi.fn();

        const gameStateContextMock = {
            bestScore: 12939,
            playerScores: [],
        }
        
        render(
            <GameStateContext.Provider value={gameStateContextMock}>
                <DatabaseProvider value={{handleLoginClick: mockHandleLoginClick}}>
                    <StartupScreen />
                </DatabaseProvider>
            </GameStateContext.Provider>
        );

        const user = userEvent.setup();


        const loginButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /log in with google/i });

        await user.click(loginButton);

        expect(loginButton).toBeInTheDocument();

        expect(mockHandleLoginClick).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

I'm aware that my test isn't really complete but I've had such a hard time getting the tests to actually run because values are missing. I've tried mocking some of the context values but its getting excessive.

I guess i'm mostly looking for some advice on how I should approach testing this component when its tied up with lots of context usage. I'm quite new to testing React components.

If you're wanting to see my test file and the component itself I've provided the github links below:

Test file => https://github.com/ItsWakana/Photo-tagging-app/blob/feat/testing/src/tests/UserLogin.test.jsx

StartupScreen component => https://github.com/ItsWakana/Photo-tagging-app/blob/feat/testing/src/components/StartupScreen.jsx

Appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Instead of calling `useContext` directly, wrap you contexts and consume them via custom hooks. It makes the code clearer, and for testing you can just mock out the custom hooks. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850880/usecontext-not-updating-on-state-change-in-react/68851743#68851743

Comment: Would this mean I don't need to pass all my variables and methods through the value attribute of the context provider? I could return all the different state from a provider in a custom hook? Then just import that hook in the module that needs it? Edit. I suppose I would still need to give these values to the provider or else the useContext wouldn't work.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but why the `init` prop passed to the contextProvider? Wouldn't it be better for the state to be defined inside the contextProvider itself? Seems odd to provide all my state outside the context that I want to store my state/

Comment: That's because you're thinking like an application developer and not a library author. If you want to provide a fully general context store as a library you have to expose a way for the consumer to pass in an initial state as part of the API :)

Comment: If I'm doing something like `const userState = useUserContextState();` inside of my StartupScreen to access the userState using the custom hook, I'm assuming its okay that I won't always be using all of the properties/methods from that user hook? Different components require different variables/methods but the hook would be returning ALL these values even if I don't always need them. That is okay I assume? Edit: Unless its standard to destructure the values you need from the custom context hook? Like `const { user } = useUserContextState();` Not sure if doing that would effect testing

Comment: Appreciate the help, I've got these lines in my StartupScreen component now:

`const userState = useUserContextState();`

 `const { gameStarted, toggleGameState } = useGameStateContext();`

  `const { handleLoginClick } = useDatabaseContext();`

I'm unsure how to go about mocking these in my vitest tests?

Comment: I assumed you were using something like jest which allows mocking those imports (and unlike mocking core React hooks won't break other stuff that relies on them). Vitest docs *says* it's jest compatible, so it should hopefully still work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using vitest but I think mocking is also used in the same way. I've been looking into mocks but not sure how to do it with my own setup. Do you think mocking is an okay approach in this instance or would it be better to pass in these context values as props to the components that need it?

Comment: Nah. Just mock out your custom hook to access the context