# Cannot Read Property of Undefined Reading "name" React Context Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mern, 2d-context-api

I'am trying to create context and the app state in a same file but I'am getting this runtime and undefined error

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const NoteContext = createContext({ name: "default" });

export default function NoteState(props) {
  const obj = {
    name: "johnsmilga",
    email:"johndoe343@gmail.com"
  };

  return (
    <NoteContext.Provider value={obj}>
      {props.children}
    </NoteContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

that's my notecontext while i wrap my all components inside my app.js file but when i click on my about page to get the context name value it throws undefined error. But when Iam creating a seprate file for context like this

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const NoteContext = createContext({ name: "default" });

export default NoteContext
```

and a NoteState file like this.

```
import NoteContext from "./NoteContext";

export default function NoteState(props) {
  const obj = {
    name: "wasay",
    email:"wasay0010@gmail.com"
  };

  return (
    <NoteContext.Provider value={obj}>
      {props.children}
    </NoteContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

then it's working fine but ican't understand why this happens althought my above code is correct then why react throw error on the above code and throwing the error when seprate the code into different files can someone explain this

i just want my code in a single file i tried it but it get's me an error but when seprate the code into different files it works as i expected

Comment: We need more info on how do you have "undefined error".

Comment: In your single file example you don't export the context, how are consumers supposed to consume it with `useContext`? In general though I recommend the approach I outline [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850880/usecontext-not-updating-on-state-change-in-react/68851743#68851743)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:-

```js
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useGetProfileQuery } from '../store/services/profleServices'

// Create the context
export const ProfileContext = createContext()

// Provider component
export const ProfileProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { data: profileData = {}, isSuccess } = useGetProfileQuery({})

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('in context data useEffect', profileData)
    if (profileData && isSuccess) {
      console.log('in context data', profileData)
      setProfile(profileData)
    }
  }, [profileData, isSuccess])

  // State to hold the profile data
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({})

  // Provide the profile and updateProfile function to the children components
  return (
        <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ profile, setProfile }}>
            {children}
        </ProfileContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful to the OP, but it doesn't actually answer the question, which is why the OPs code stops working when they try to put it all in the same file.